# return List<String> from string that can be split by words and then appended in Java

Tags: java, string, split

For instance, if I have the string "Bob Bakes Brownies", is there any way I can get this method to produce a list of three strings: "Bob", "Bob Bakes", and "Bob Bakes Brownies"
Any feed back would be appreciated.

Comment: you can use .split(" ") and string concatenate

Answer (score 1):

Create a list to return.  Loop through the `String` looking for spaces.  For each space that you find, add a substring to the list, that starts at the zero index and goes up to the space (not including the space).

When there are no more spaces, add the entire string to the list, and return.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .split() to get an array of the individual words or use StringTokenizer

Answer (score 0):

Good approach will be `split(" ")` the string, this will produce an array. Then you can iterate on the array when every time you concatenate the current array cell with `StringBuilder` or a normal concatenation and print the result on every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

public void listOfStrings(String s){

```
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    int p = 0;


    for (int i = 0; i < s.length() ; i++) {

         if(s.charAt(i) == ' ') {
             result.add(p, s.substring(0, i));
             p++;
         }
        if(i == s.length()-1)
            result.add(p,s);


    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
static List<String> createStringList(String string) {
    String[] parts = string.split(" ");
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    StringBuilder currentString = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
        if (i > 0) {
            currentString.append(" ");
        }
        currentString.append(parts[i]);
        result.add(currentString.toString());
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`public ArrayList<String> solution(String s){`

```
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    String[] array = s.split(" ");

    for(String str:array){
        sb.append(str);
        result.add(sb.toString());
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
String string = "Bob Bakes Brownies";
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(string.split(" "));
```

Comment: This would return a list with three elements "Bob","Bakes" and "Brownies" which is not the expected result.

Comment: No matter how many times I look at this: 
For instance, if I have the string "Bob Bakes Brownies", is there any way I can get this method to produce a list of three strings: "Bob", "Bob Bakes", and "Bob Bakes Brownies" 
I do not understand why this post got downvotes. Is it because the returned list is immutable? To modify the result list in this scenario is not realistic.

Comment: It got downvotes because it doesn't do what was asked for.  I want to know why it got an upvote.